# Ember: how do I set an attribute of a controller of mine to be the text of a file in the app

Tags: ember.js

How can I set an attribute  of a controller to be the text of a file in the app at transpile time...

This would save me from having a bunch of long, ugly text in the conroller

Comment: Do you want to import file contents into a controller?

Comment: import is a loaded word. I would like an attribute of my controller to be assigned the text in separate text file at transpile time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ember-cli-json-module](https://github.com/IvyApp/ember-cli-json-module) to import a JSON data structure and assign one of its values to a property.

If JSON doesn't fit you, consider studying the sources of the addon and replicating its functionality with simple file reads.